# When I try to log on to Exact Online, I get an Oops, something went wrong error

Tags: exact-online, invantive-data-hub

When I try to log on to Exact Online using Invantive Data Hub, I get an error message my username and password is wrong while I am very sure it is correct (it has been for weeks already).

When I try to log on using Exact Online itself, I get an *Oops, something went wrong* error (in Dutch: *Oeps! Er is een fout opgetreden*):

> [image: the error message from exact online]

What is happening here? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to:

- Stop all Data Hub jobs.
- Change the password of the user involved first in Exact Online.
- Then change the scripts which have a hard-coded password or encrypted password.
- Best to use an encrypted password which is the plain text password encrypted using a device-bound public/private pair interned into Windows. See below. Note: you can NOT use the encrypted password on another device, you will need to create a new one bound to that device.
- Test and re-enable Data Hub jobs.

## Generate encrypted password

There are two ways to generate an encrypted password, which works for any supported platform:

1. Using Query Tool
2. Using Data Hub

Using the Query Tool you can generate the encrypted password as follows on the device on which you want to use the encrypted password in scripts:

- Go to Editor menu.
- Select 'Create Data Hub Batch Script'.
- Enter the password.
- Check 'Encrypt password with device key'.
- Save the batch file.
- Use the syntax with encrypted password, which will resemble:

  `"%INVANTIVE_PRG%" /user:"%INVANTIVE_USR%" /connection:"%INVANTIVE_CONN%" /encryptedpassword:"%INVANTIVE_ENCRYPTED_PWD%" /file:"%INVANTIVE_SQL_FILE%" /logfile:"%INVANTIVE_LOG_FILE%" /logoverwrite:"%INVANTIVE_LOG_FILE_OVERWRITE%" /interactive:%INVANTIVE_INTERACTIVE%`

Using Data Hub, you can generate an encrypted password as follows:

- Log on to Dummy provider or some other provider.
- Enter 'local encrypt password'.
- Follow the prompt:
  [image: Password encryption]
- Put the encrypted password in the batch file.

## Find the batch file (edited)

When you don't know the location of the scheduled batch file, you can find it in the Task Scheduler:

- Start Task Scheduler.
- Go to the list of active tasks.
- Select the task:[image: Find batch file]

Comment: How can I find the location of the batch file? It runs unattended.

Comment: @goombah Thx, added it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reported outage with Exact Online due to a massive password reset on their side. Quite some users are experiencing problems.

You can read the general announcement on the [Exact Online site](https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/DocView.aspx?DocumentID=33d0f0cc-9f9d-4ef9-9758-3cedb223706f&_Division_=1). It seems there has been a security breach with some of their customers.

There is nothing you can do except then trying to [reset your password](https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/SysForgotPassword.aspx?_Division_=1) using Exact Online, but it seems there are buried under the current massive load.

After you have done that, you have to change the password in the configuration of Invantive Data Hub.